# Pip upgrade in virtual environment access denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

(Windows 10, python 3.9.13, in command prompt as administrator) I was beginning to learn tensorflow, and followed the steps on their website. When I tried to use the command "pip install --upgrade pip" in virtual environment, it shows me the following message:

---

Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages (22.0.4)
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-22.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Attempting uninstall: pip
Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
Uninstalling pip-22.0.4:
Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-r4o_l0mr\pip.exe'
Check the permissions.

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm wondering why the tensorflow website didn't have the "-m" though.

Comment: @Cs_J  Not sure, but im glad it worked